# 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' loading initial data in django

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to get familiar with loading initial data in to a model with loaddata. So my json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "model": "locations.location",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Cafe"
    }
  }
]
```

My model.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date added', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField('date modified', default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and then when I do `python manage.py loaddata mydata`  I get

> django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing
>   fixture '/path/to/locations/fixtures/mydata.json': 'int' object has no
>   attribute 'replace'

What does that mean? I also tried changing this in the `models.py`

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

to

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name.get_full_name()
```

but didn't work. What is this int object?

More Traceback:

```
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 90, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 141, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 84, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 78, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 104, in Deserializer
    data[Model._meta.pk.attname] = Model._meta.pk.to_python(d.get("pk", None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2404, in to_python
    return uuid.UUID(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 131, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
```

Comment: Is that all your mydata.json file?

Comment: yes, i want to try it out if it works so I want to add one field to my model

Comment: Show your model, please.

Comment: Do you have more traceback information? Something's clearly expecting a string but getting an int.

Comment: ok updated ,thanks !

Comment: I have to admit I don't know what UUIDField does exactly, but is a normal IntegerField not sufficient here? I bet that would solve the error too.

Comment: The problem is here: `"pk": 1` as you can see `1` is not an UUID value.

Comment: You have `"pk": 1` and `id = models.UUIDField`.

Comment: This shows how important is share all the code involved, because, at first, if we don't see your model `"pk": 1` looks correct, but it isn't as you can see then.

Comment: Check out the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) for how to properly format a UUID.

Comment: ok, thanks, does anyone know how to set the date_field? as in getting the datenow(). Do I have to define that in json or is there a way for python to define that itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works thanks to all the comments:

```
[
  {
    "model": "locations.location",
    "fields": {
        "id":"a3184190-0b97-4c56-8aac-eeee8875aaa2",
        "name": "Cafe"
    }
  }
]
```